How to compare pricing models?
Say there is model A and model B to price vanilla European and American options. Both are calibrated against market prices

How to determine what model provides more accurate prices for either European/American/Exotic options?
How to determine what model provides more accurate greeks for hedging?
How new models are being assesed in real world when deciding whether new model shall be used instead of the one being used now?



You have to be more clear. Prices for what? If it is for the same options it is calibrated to, then the calibration error is an obvious answer. Otherwise you need to explain exactly what you want to do.
Greeks: which ones? For which products? I guess greeks used to hedge: so obvious choices are delta and rho, but vega too. A better greek is normally the one that generates a better replication. You will have to test your model on many scenarios (real / simulated???) and see the distribution of the replication error (mean and variance at least).
What makes a good model? Not an easy answer.

In my opinion, these are some of the key features of a good / better model (in no particular order)

Does it have a robust numerical implementation?
Is it fast enough for its target usage?
Does it produce stable risks?
How hard is it to calibrate it to market prices?
Do I understand its output?
Are the parameters well identified (so orthogonal or with a clear meaning)?
How long will it take to explain it to the desk? Anything that needs more than 5 minutes is too complicated and likely to have already failed some point above
Backtesting: does it show any decent backtesting results? But this is a very tricky point anyway.
Do we need a single model for al products? Another very difficult question. In theory yes, but in practice, things are very different.
Does it capture the relevant risks of the target products?

I am sure there are plenty mode which I have forgotten.

Thank you, that was very helpful. For pricing I meant either pricing what you calibrated against or exotic products. For greeks I meant greeks used for hedging.
What if both models have very low calibration error? How would one assess what model prices derivatives better?

You should check the calibration error, but for exotic it won't be your main driver. Local volatility has 0 (in theory) calibration error, but you cant use for exotic products. You will need a more qualitative analysis: if the 2 models price the exotic differently, why is that? what is that one captures more than the other? Is it reasonable? Can one of the 2 become a subset of the other? I have seen multiple models (stacked on top of each others) used for a single product: only one was able to fit the smile and only the other one was able to capture key risks.
